# How can I copy the data from one table to the other table?

Tags: vb.net

Can you help me correct my code below? I want to insert the Employee ID and Name from the table1 to table2 together with the date which is in label1 and creator in label2. I don’t know how to insert the value from the label....

My Code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EMPINFO_DEL ([DATE],[CREATOR]) SELECT *, VALUES('" + Trim(Label1.Text) & "-" & Trim(Label2.Text) + "') FROM  EMPINFO_TBL  WHERE EMPID =" & UCase(Trim(Text1.Text)) & ""

Label1.Text=Mitchel 'Creator
Label2.Text=26Mar20 'Date
```

```
EMPINFO_DEL
EMPID
NAME
DATE
CREATOR

EMPINFO_TBL
EMPID
NAME
```

Comment: Tweak it to do what? We can't read your mind. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR description of what you're trying to achieve and exactly how what you have fails to do that.

Comment: Sorry, for finding it vaguely. What I want to achieve is to copy the data with Employee ID-12345 from Table1 to Table2 but I want to put the value also from the form which is Label1 and Label2 for user and date. Hope this clears. Thank you.

Comment: No one should have to read comments to understand your question. Edit the question and add all the information that should have been there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, `Label` controls are for displaying data, not for storing data. You should not be retrieving any data from `Label` for use anywhere else. If you have a date that you want to use then you should have it stored in a `Date` variable. If you want to display that date then you get the value from that variable, format it and display it in the `Label` but, when you want to use the value for something else, you get it from the variable, not from the `Label`. The same goes for the creator.

With regards to the query part of your SQL, the `SELECT` clause specifies the values you want to retrieve. That usually involves column names but you can use other expressions that evaluate to an appropriate value too. In this case, you should pass in the date and the creator via parameters and then use those parameters in the `SELECT` clause. Your `INSERT INTO` clause then specifies all the columns you want to insert into. Without having tested, your code should look something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO EMPINFO_DEL (EMPID, NAME, [DATE], CREATOR)
SELECT EMPID, NAME, @DATE, @CREATOR
FROM EMPINFO_TBL
WHERE EMPID = @EMPID"

With cmd.Parameters
    .Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateVariable
    .Add("@CREATOR", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = creatorVariable
    .Add("@EMPID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = empIdVariable
End With
```

Comment: Hi jm let me try your recommendation later and let you know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi jmcilhinney, just tried it and it works. Thank you so much, you've been a great help. With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Trim(Date.Now.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD"))
                .Add("@USER", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = UCase(Trim(Form1.Label2.Text)) & "-" & Trim(Form1.Label5.Text)

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo!!! DO NOT use `Strings` for dates. Use `Dates`. That's why the data type exists.DO NOT do this:`.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Trim(Date.Now.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD"))`. If you want to zero the time on a `Date` then get it's `Date` property, e.g. `.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date.Now.Date`. That said, if you want today's date without the time, don't use `Date.Now` in the first place. That's exactly what `Date.Today` is for: `.Add("@DATE", SqlDbType.Date).Value = Date.Today`.

Comment: Also, if you insist on ignoring everything I said about the right way to get the `Strings` for the other parameters, at least don't write VB6 code to do it the wrong way: `.Add("@USER", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = $"{Form1.Label2.Text.Trim().ToUpper()}-{Form1.Label5.Text.Trim()}"`.

Comment: Finally, the fact that you were trimming the result of `Date.Now.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD")` just proves that you're trimming for no good reason. There is no possibility of that `String` having leading or trailing spaces so what possible reason could you have for trimming it? Don't write any code for no reason. Every bit of code you write should be to achieve something specific that you have considered and knows is required. If you're trimming text that can't possibly need trimming, you're not putting enough thought into it.

Comment: Sorry, been so busy due to corona virus, I have just changed the data type from varchar to date...Thank you.